# How can I style elements in a div based on the div's class?

Tags: html, css, themes, styling

Basically, I'm creating a dark theme system for my website, and it adds the `dark` class to the html tag when the proper function is called.  I'm using CSS variables like `--light-theme-bg: white;` and accessing them with `var(--light-theme-bg);`.  How can I style specific elements such as `hr` based on if that `dark` class is attached to the `html` element.  How can I do this?

Comment: Can you  edit the question and the css and html laid out a bit in a file or two files inline, so someone can just work with your your question and turn it directly into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) is your friend. You'll need to add two rules to your CSS. One for the dark theme and one for the light one.

In those rules, you can define a `--background` var.

All child elements that reference that var will respect it.

```css
.light {
  --background: #f9f9f9;
}

.dark {
  --background: #191919;
}

.first,
.second {
  color: red;
  background: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<div class="light">
  <div class="first"> I'm the first div</div>
  <div class="second">I'm the second div</div>
</div>

<div class="dark">
  <div class="first"> I'm the first div</div>
  <div class="second">I'm the second div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an `element` inside a `.class`, use the css syntax `.class element`, so your code would be `.dark hr` to select it an `hr` element inside an element with the class of `.dark`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention It added "dark" class to the parent html tag. So considering dark as parent class you can use css to all element like
.dark elements(h1/div/p/others)

Comment: Well yes, but then wouldn't the JavaScript have to add the `dark` class to ALL elements?

Comment: I think not because it added to the parent element class at the first encounter I guess . So you can use that parent class and customize css of others child elements or class .